# Increment time in ngx material timepicker fields

Tags: angular, timepicker

I have two ngx material timepicker fields (https://agranom.github.io/ngx-material-timepicker/) one for start time and one for end time. The functionality required is that whenever user selects time in start time field, I need to automatically add 1 hour to the end time field. So if user selects 9AM then automatically endtime will be 10AM. I'm not sure how to achieve this because the timepicker fields return time in string format like: "09:00" or "10:00".

[image: Current implementation]

How can I automatically add 1 hour to end time upon selection of start time

Answer (score 2):

A bit of a hacky way -
You can split the time based on the `:` character, then convert the first part (hour) into a number. Then you can set the end time to that number incremented, concatenated with `:` and the second part of the split (minutes)

so in your `if(type=='startTime)` bracket, you add the logic.

in pseudocode:

```
let splits = event.split(':'); // splits should have an array with two values, based on the value. for ex, given the time '11:23', it will be an array ['11','23']
hours = +(splits[0]) // take the first value and numberify it. so in the prev ex, take '11' and make it 11
let endHour = hours+1 // don't forget to add logic for midnight etc (not included)
let newtimestring = endHour.tostring() + ':' + splits[1] // create the new endtime with the incremented hour concatenated with the minutes
```

then you set this value as your end time

Answer (score 1):

```
//function    

 timeEvent(event:any, time:any)
 {
    if(time === 'endTime'){
    //convert event value to date
        let date = new Date(event.target.value);
    //add 1 hour
        date.setHours(date.getHours()+1)
     }
  }
```